# Apache server turns php files lowercase

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am having a strange apache issue. I deployed a laravel project to my webserver. But I am getting this error:

> ReflectionException (-1)
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\controller does not exist

Controller does exist but starts with uppercase (Laravel default controller). I am not sure why my bluehost server looks for php files with all lowercase letters. I contacted bluehost incase it was a server issue but they said they couldn't help.

When I change Controller to lowercase it would be found, but changing every php file in my project to lowercase seems like a temp fix, rather then a soultion.

Any suggestions or relevent threads would be appreciated!

Comment: check your .htaccess file? Anything funky going on with rewrites?

Comment: this is my htaccess in my public folder: https://pastebin.com/g4AXrdfE.

Comment: What is the route statement?

Comment: Locally it expects uppercase controller names, so in my routes file I use capital to being the class name. 

Update on the htaccess, when i remove the htaccess from public and root directory I get the same error